# How to add Jfrog Artifactory as a HELM registry in Spinnaker

Tags: kubernetes-helm, artifactory, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am trying to add the Jfrog Artifactory to spinnaker so that spinnaker will be able to fetch the helm chart and makes the deployment. I am trying this command but it's not working

```
hal config artifact helm account add my-helm-account \
    --username-password-file $USERNAME_PASSWORD_FILE
```

When I run the pipeline it shows me this error

```
Status: 500, URL: http://spin-clouddriver.spinnaker:7002/artifacts/fetch/, Message: Failed to download index.yaml file in
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to provide the `--repository` flag as well. I'm guessing that spin-clouddriver URL is the default if a repository isn't specified.

The final hal command may look like this:
`hal config artifact helm account add my-helm-account --username-password-file $USERNAME_PASSWORD_FILE --repository https://my.artifactory.com/artifactory/helm`

Reference for the command: https://spinnaker.io/docs/reference/halyard/commands/#hal-config-artifact-helm-account-add